# wp_insert_post question

Tags: posts

with the wp_insert_post i want to insert text from a html-form. This is my string i want to insert:

```
[code]
#include<stdio.h>

int main() {
printf("Hello World\n");
return 0;
}[/code]
```

when i publish the post it looks like this:
[image: Sourcecode in Wordpress post]

"Hello Worldn" should be "Hello World\n" and stdio.h after } should not be there.
EDIT:
It should look like this:
[image]

Comment: so whats the issue??

Comment: "Hello Worldn" should be "Hello World\n" and </stdio.h> after } should not be there.

Comment: Just to be clear, the issue is that it's removing backslashes right?

Comment: Where is the `[code]` shortcode coming from? I fail to see anything like that referred in [Codex docs](https://codex.wordpress.org/Shortcode).

Answer (score 1):

You need to add slashes as `wp_insert_post` will remove them:

```
$data = array(
    'post_content' => '[code]
#include<stdio.h>

int main() {
    printf("Hello World\n");
    return 0;
}
[/code]',
);

wp_insert_post( wp_slash( $data ) );
```

**Update:** After running the above, this is *exactly* what I get in the editor:

```
[code]
#include

int main() {
printf("Hello World\n");
return 0;
}
[/code]
```

Comment: printf("Hello World
 
");
Is the result of this.

Comment: I just tested my snippet on a local install and have updated my answer with *exactly* what the editor looks like when editing the post.